# How to select data from a range within a density in R

Tags: r, density-plot

Not sure about how to tackle this - I have a data distribution where data selection based on standard deviation does not include all data points (data is more variable on one end than on the other). However, when plotting a density plot I can see that all data outside the 8th blue ring are what I want to select.

Example code:

```
x <- sort(rnorm(1300, mean = 0, sd = 1))
y <- rnorm(1300, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x <- c(x, rnorm(300, mean = 4, sd = 2), rnorm(600, mean = -2, sd = 2))
y <- c(y, rnorm(300, mean = 3, sd = 4), rnorm(600, mean = -2, sd = 2))

mydata <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(cex = 0.5) +
  geom_density_2d()
```

Comment: Well, what do you want? Do you want help examining the `ggplot` object to find the nth blue ring and select points in it? Or do you want a graphical method for selecting points? Or just better methods for outlier elimination than standard deviation?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to identify is a 'standard deviation of bivariate data'. In my data, selecting data outside the n-th ring would accomplish this. But I have no grasp of how to implement something like this. I do not need a graphical method, only to visualize the result (which is answered by Jon Spring below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adapted this from http://slowkow.com/notes/ggplot2-color-by-density/.
Under the hood, `geom_density_2d` uses the `MASS::kde2d` function, so we can also apply it to the underlying data to subset by density.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sort(rnorm(1300, mean = 0, sd = 1))
y <- rnorm(1300, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x <- c(x, rnorm(300, mean = 4, sd = 2), rnorm(600, mean = -2, sd = 2))
y <- c(y, rnorm(300, mean = 3, sd = 4), rnorm(600, mean = -2, sd = 2))

mydata <- data.frame(x,y) 

# Copied from http://slowkow.com/notes/ggplot2-color-by-density/
get_density <- function(x, y, n = 100) {
  dens <- MASS::kde2d(x = x, y = y, n = n)
  ix <- findInterval(x, dens$x)
  iy <- findInterval(y, dens$y)
  ii <- cbind(ix, iy)
  return(dens$z[ii])
}
mydata$density <- get_density(mydata$x, mydata$y)
```

**Select points based on arbitrary contour**

EDIT: Changed to allow selection based on contour levels

```
# First create plot with geom_density
gg <- ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(cex = 0.5) +
  geom_density_2d(size = 1, n = 100)
gg

# Extract levels denoted by contours by going into the 
#   ggplot build object. I found these coordinates by 
#   examining the object in RStudio; Note, the coordinates 
#   would change if the layer order were altered.
gb <- ggplot_build(gg)
contour_levels <- unique(gb[["data"]][[2]][["level"]])
# contour_levels
# [1] 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08

# Add layer that relies on given contour level
gg2 <- gg +
  geom_point(data = mydata %>% 
               filter(density <= contour_levels[1]), 
             color = "red", size = 0.5)
gg2
```

[image]

Comment: While this would work, could you elaborate on how to select density < 0.01? How can this be applied to general data sets without trial and error?

Comment: Would this be a viable approach: limit <- quantile(mydata$density)[2] and then filter(density < limit) ?